# How to add views to current layout file when navigation drawer class is extended

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

This is my navigation drawer class

```
public class NavigationDrawer extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
public DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
public ListView listView;
public String menu[];
public ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation_drawer);
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    listView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_drawer_lv);
    menu=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu);
    listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, menu));
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    toolbar=(android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    drawerToggle=new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,R.string.open_nav_drawer,R.string.close_nav_drawer) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            Toast.makeText(NavigationDrawer.this,"opened",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            Toast.makeText(NavigationDrawer.this,"closed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        }

    };
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    //actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
    drawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.cart) {
        Toast.makeText(NavigationDrawer.this, "cart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
    /*if (id == R.id.search) {
        Toast.makeText(NavigationDrawer.this, "search", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }*/
    if(drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Toast.makeText(this,menu[position],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_register, menu);


    return true;
}
}
```

and xml file of navigation drawer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer_llout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <include layout="@layout/app_bar" android:id="@+id/app_bar"/>

</FrameLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/DarkOliveGreen"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="37dp">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/profile1"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:text="Username"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer_lv"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:entries="@array/menu"
        android:divider="@null"
        >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

and NavDrawer2 activity extends above activity Navigation drawer....
NavDrawer2 class is

```
public class NavDrawer2 extends NavigationDrawer implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_nav_drawer2);
    //Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    ////////////////////////////////
    android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar;
    toolbar=(android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    //actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    ///////////////////////////////



}

}
```

and xml of NavDrawer2 is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.example.vamshi.joco.NavDrawer2"
android:orientation="vertical">
<include android:id="@+id/app_bar2" layout="@layout/activity_navigation_drawer" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="iam happy"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
    android:textSize="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="iam very happy"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/tv1"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

The problem with this code is textviews in NavDrawer2 are going out of screen and not able to see textviews.
please tell me how to solve this problem?